# Selenium webdriver 2.41.0 with Firefox V 46 and Chrome V 51

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium 2.41.0 that works fine with all versions of IE 11, but  it is not supporting Firefox 46.0 and Chrome 51 [Chrome supports till 50th version with the latest driver 2.21]. Could anyone guide me what I need to do to support latest versions of Firefox and Chrome? Do I need to upgrade Web driver or Firefox/Chrome Drivers.

Comment: Please update your all browser.. and use latest version of selenium which is 2.53.0 from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/.. It will solve your all problem...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated  webdriver to 2.53.0  now it works fine for firefox v46.0 but I have chrome v 51, The driver for chrome that I have installed [latest] supports chrome v46-50 only and I am not getting chrome older version [46-50].

Comment: I´m having problem too. I´m using chromedriver-2.22.exe and Chrome 51.0.2704.106. WebDriver open up the browser, but it stucks with "data:," in the address bar. Then, after a few seconds, the log shows _Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed_

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to work with latest version Chrome (v 51 as of now) update your
   selenium chrome driver to latest according to your browser version.
2. To work with Firefox v46 and above you need to use gecko driver by using     latest version of selenium jars v3.0.1.